# How best to return newly added entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've just noticed that the add method no longer returns the entity when successfully added to a DbSet and I'm at a bit of a loss as to why as its been a consistent feature of Add() in both EF 5 and 6.

I know that I can achieve something similar by using a try catch when I add the entity and simply return the results of a query as such

```
try
{
    Cars.Add(new Car { Make = "Ford", Model = "Focus", Year = 2016, Use = "Rally" });

    return Cars.SingleOrDefault(car => car.Make == "Ford", Model == "Focus");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

In this I already see problems which brings me to what I'm really looking for. Because Add() is no longer returning an object what is the best or correct approach to doing this?

Comment: How are you passing in your DbContext object to your method?

Answer (score -1):

Well, you do not really need the Add method to return anything including the object that you just added because you already have that object!

In the example below, once I add the car to the Cars DbSet and call SaveChanges(), EF will populate car Id with the generated primary key from the database and will start tracking this object for future changes:

```
Car car = new Car { Make = "Ford", Model = "Focus", Year = 2016, Use = "Rally" }
Cars.Add(car);

dbContext.SaveChanges();

// car object is ready to use!
```

Comment: I gave you downvote as it does not answer OP question. I actually have a same problem where quering databasecontext does not return newly added entities without calling savechanges.